# Chart function suggestions

Tags: python, django, charts, model

hope you are doing well ! 
I want to create Charts based on my models , I want you to advice me some chart ideas , I couldn't figure out what should I put in my view function can you help me out

*PS : I already used some simple models and the charts was quite easy but those models are so hard I hope you can advice me*

```
    from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
    class Country(models.Model):
        Country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{} '.format(self.Country)

    class Reason(models.Model):
        Reason_cd = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        Reason_NM = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.Reason_NM)

    class Mesure(models.Model):
        Mesure_cd = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        Mesure_NM = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.Mesure_NM)

    class Client(models.Model):
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        Adresse = models.CharField(max_length=560)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        code_postal = models.IntegerField()
        phone number = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
        mail = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}, {}'.format(self.last_name,self.first_name)

    class Delivery_Agent(models.Model):
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}, {}  '.format(self.last_name,self.first_name)

    class Office(models.Model):
        office_cd = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        office_NM = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}, {}  '.format(self.office_cd,self.office_NM)

    class Mail_item_Event(models.Model):
        mail_item_fid = models.CharField(max_length=36)
        Event_cd = models.IntegerField(auto_created=True,unique=True) #Event code
        office_Evt_cd = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Evt')
        Date_Evt = models.DateTimeField()
        Date_Capture = models.DateTimeField()
        Next_office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Next_office')
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.Event_cd)

    class Delivery_info(models.Model):
        mail_item_fid = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Event_cd = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="delivery_infor_event_cd")
        office_Evt_cd = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Evt2')
        Date_Evt = models.DateTimeField()
        Agent_delivery_cd = models.ForeignKey(Delivery_Agent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='agentDelivery')
        Signatory_NM = models.OneToOneField(Delivery_Agent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='signatory')
        Raison_Non_Delivery_cd = models.ForeignKey(Reason,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='raisonNonDelivery', blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}, {} '.format(self.Signatory_NM,self.mail_item_fid)

    class mail_items(models.Model):
        mail_item_fid = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Event_cd = models.OneToOneField(Mail_item_Event,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="mail_item_event_cd")
        office_Evt_cd = models.ForeignKey(Office,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office_Ev')
        Date_Evt = models.DateTimeField()
        Country_origine = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,related_name='paysOrigine')
        Country_destination = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='paysDestination')
        Expediteur = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='expedi')
        Destinateur = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='destin')
```

Comment: I got an idea is to count **mail_items** per **countries** so I did new class named **mail_item_count** with two columns **country** and the **counter** also I used signals to update this class , if you have any other ideas please don't hesitate to write me your answers